# Showing a filter on the Power set of $\mathbb{Z}$ is a one point Filter

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

Let $\mathcal{P}_0(X)$ the Power set of $X$ without the empty set and let $\dot{x}:=\{A\subseteq X: x \in A\}$ the one point filter generated by $x$. Furtermore let $$ \mathcal{A} := \{ f \in X^{\mathcal{P}_0(X)} : \ \forall A \in \mathcal{P}_0(X): f(A) \in A\} $$ be the set of the functions mapping subsets of the power set to elements of them. Let $\varphi$ be a filter on $\mathcal{P}_0(X)$ with $$\forall f \in \mathcal{A} \exists x_f \in X : f[\varphi]=\dot{x}_f.$$
Here $f[\varphi]$ stands for the filter generated from the filter basis:
$$  \{ \operatorname{image} f|_M \ : \ M \in \varphi\}$$

It seems like our definition of filter is not the standard definition, to avoid confusion $\varphi \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$

> Now we shall show that if $X=\mathbb{Z}$, then it follows that $\varphi$ is a one point filter.  From the given property we already can conclude that $\varphi$ is an ultrafilter but I don't know what I shall do next, could someone give me a hint?

As it was asked for in the comments, our definition of a filter is:

> Let $S$ be a set (an arbitrary one), and $A,B\subseteq S$. We call $\varphi\subset \mathcal{P}(S)$ a filter when the following holds
>
> - $\varnothing\notin \varphi$
> - $A,B\in \varphi \implies A\cap B \in \varphi$
> - $A\subset B $ and $A\in \varphi \implies B\in \varphi$

An ultrafilter is a filter, such that there is no bigger filter, e.g. when $G$ is a filter and $F$ is an ultra filter and $G\supseteq F\implies G=F$. More convenient is the equivalence that for every subset $A$ of $S$ it holds that $A\in F \vee S\setminus A \in F$. The one point filter is already defined in the first sentence.

I posted the question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129720/showing-a-filter-with-a-certain-property-on-the-power-set-of-mathbbz-is-a-on) were someone wrote the answer.

Comment: Isn't $f\[ \phi \]$ as defined above just a subset of $X$? So how can it be a filter on $X$, i.e. a set of subsets of $X$?

Comment: @AlexanderThumm $f[\phi]$ is a family of subsets of $X$, I edited the post and hopes this clarifies it

Comment: By definition of $\mathcal A$, it would seem that $$\mathcal B_f:=\{f(M):M\in\varphi\}$$ is a set of **elements** of $X$. To be a basis for a filter on $X$, $\mathcal B_f$ must be a set of **subsets** of $X,$ such that $\emptyset\notin\mathcal B_f$, and such that for any $A,B\in\mathcal B_f$ there is some $C\in\mathcal B_f$ with $C\subseteq A\cap B.$ Perhaps, we could have the elements of $\mathcal A$ map sets to singleton subsets, rather than elements? That might fix things.

Comment: @CameronBuie $\varphi$ is a filter on the power set so $M$ is a subset of the power set, and and element of it is a subset again

Comment: What is the origin of this question, what is its motivation?

Comment: Ah! I see it now. Still, the definition of $\mathcal A$ needs fixed to accommodate that.

Comment: @yup topology group exercise is its origin and the motivation is I didn't solved it while the group exercise

Comment: @Cameron what need to be fixed in the definition of $\mathcal{A}$ ?

Comment: As it stands, the members of $\mathcal A$ are functions on $\mathcal{P}_0(X)$. But the members of $\varphi$ are members of $\mathcal{P}\bigl(\mathcal{P}(X)\bigr)$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about $f(M)$ for $f\in\mathcal A$ and $M\in\varphi$.

Comment: @CameronBuie nope an element of a subset of the powerset of the power set is an element of the power set isn't it ?

Comment: True, but I don't see how that matters. The $M\in\varphi$ are *not* elements of the powerset. Rather, they are subsets of the powerset. Unless, by $f(M)$, in that case, you mean $\{f(x):x\in M\}$? That would make sense, but I'd denote that as $\text{ran}(f|_M)$ (where $f|_M$ denotes the restriction of $f$ to $M$), to avoid confusion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8630/discussion-between-dominic-michaelis-and-cameron-buie)

Comment: For whatever reason, it isn't letting me type in chat, nor letting me log in. Let's use an even simpler example, though, letting $X=\{0\}.$ Then $$\mathcal{P}_0(X)=\bigl\{\{0\}\bigr\},$$ and $$\mathcal{P}_0\bigl(\mathcal{P}_0(X)\bigr)=\Bigl\{\bigl\{\{0\}\bigr\}\Bigr\}.$$ But $\bigl\{\{0\}\bigr\}$ is not in the domain of $f\in\mathcal A$. Rather, it **is** the domain of $f$. That's why I suggested that $f(M)$ may be intended to indicate the image of $M$ under $f$.

Comment: @CameronBuie thanks for the patience does it work now ?

Comment: Perfect!

P.S.: I have been thinking on the question, not just nitpicking. ;-)

Comment: Does your definition of a filter assume that $A,B\in \varphi \implies A\cap B \ne \varnothing$?

Comment: @BorisNovikov yes and this is in the normal definition. Note that I talk about finite intersections

Comment: Now [asked and answered on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129720/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that the following is not my answer nor my idea but the one of Joseph Van Name, who posted this answer on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129720/showing-a-filter-with-a-certain-property-on-the-power-set-of-mathbbz-is-a-on/129885#129885) and I just copy his answer here for completeness.

For this problem, we shall use $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ since $\mathbb{N}$ is easier to work with in this case. We shall say that $A$ has property $P$ almost everywhere (or for almost all $A$) abbreviated a.e. if $\{A\in P_{0}(X)|A\,\textrm{has property}\,P\}\in\varphi$.

For $n>0$, let $f_{n}\in\mathcal{A}$ be the function where if $A\in P_{0}(\mathbb{N})$ then $f_{n}(A)$ is the $n$-th element of $A$ whenever $|A|\geq n$ and $f_{n}(A)$ is the last element of $A$ whenever $|A|<n$. Let $y_{n}=x_{f_{n}}$. Then $f_{n}(A)=y_{n}$ for almost every $n$. If $i<j$, then clearly $y_{i}\leq y_{j}$. Furthermore, if $y_{n}=y_{n+1}$, then $f_{1}(A)=y_{1},...,f_{n+1}(A)=y_{n+1}$ for almost every $A\in P_{0}(\mathbb{N})$. However, if $f_{1}(A)=y_{1},...,f_{n+1}(A)=y_{n+1}$, then $A=\{y_{1},...,y_{n+1}\}$ making $\varphi$ a principal ultrafilter. We shall therefore assume that $y_{n}<y_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

We claim that $\varphi$ is an ultrafilter. Let $S=\{A\in P_{0}(X)|f_{1}(A)=y_{1},f_{2}(A)=y_{2}\}$. Then clearly $S\in\varphi$. Let $R\subseteq P_{0}(X)$. Let $h\in\mathcal{A}$ be a function where $h(A)=y_{1}$ for each $A\in R\cap S$ and $h(A)=y_{2}$ for each $A\in R^{c}\cap S$. Then the function $h$ is constant almost everywhere. It is clear that $h(A)=y_{1}$ a.e. or $h(A)=y_{2}$ a.e. If $h(A)=y_{1}$ almost everywhere, then $R\cap S\in\varphi$. If $h(A)=y_{2}$ a.e., then $R^{c}\cap S\in\varphi$. Therefore, we conclude that either $R\in\varphi$ or $R^{c}\in\varphi$. Therefore $\varphi$ is an ultrafilter.

We shall now prove that $\varphi$ is a principal ultrafilter. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $\varphi$ is a non-principal ultrafilter. Let $Y=\{y_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. We claim that $Y\not\subseteq A$ for almost every $A$. To prove this assume that $Y\subseteq A$ for almost every $A$. Then the ultrafilter $\varphi$ is $\sigma$-complete. To see this, let $T=\{A\in P(X)|Y\subseteq A\}$, and let $P=\{R_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a partition of $T$ into countably many pieces. Let $g\in\mathcal{A}$ be a function where if $A\in R_{n}$, then $g(A)=y_{n}$. Then the function $g$ is constant almost everywhere. In particular, $g(A)=y_{n}$ for almost every $A$. However, this implies that $R_{n}\in\varphi$ for some $n$ making the ultrafilter $\varphi$ $\sigma$-complete. On the other hand, it is well known that there are no non-principal $\sigma$-ultrafilters on $P_{0}(\mathbb{N})$ since $|P_{0}(\mathbb{N})|$ is far below the first measurable cardinal if one even exists. We conclude that $Y\not\subseteq A$ for almost every $A$.

Now let $t\in\mathcal{A}$ be a function where if $y_{1}\in A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and $Y\not\subseteq A$, then $t(A)=y_{n}$ where $y_{n+1}\not\in A$. Then $t(A)=y_{n}$ for almost all $A\in P_{0}(X)$. Then the function $t$ is constant almost everywhere. In particular, $t(A)=y_{n}$ for almost all $A\in P_{0}(X)$. However, this implies that $y_{n+1}\not\in A$ for almost all $n$. This contradicts the fact that $f_{n+1}(A)=y_{n+1}$ for almost every $A\in P_{0}(X)$. We therefore conclude that $\varphi$ can only be a principal ultrafilter.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to post someone else's answer as a community wiki answer.

Comment: @TMM made it Community wiki. I asked someone in chat but seems like there has been a missunterstanding.